# Change Value in Array Java

Tags: java, arrays, type-conversion

User input a number such as `1234569775` of 10 digit. may on of the digit has a Value of X and this mean its equal to number 10  SO i write my code

```
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    String a=in.next();
    String arr[]=new String[10];
    for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        arr[i]=String.valueOf(a.charAt(i));
    }
    for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        if (arr[i]=="X")
        {
            arr[i]="10";
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
}
```

but its the value of X does not change and I try to make a new array and does not make any change too
last thing i want to change this String array all value in it to Integer so I can make any Mathematical operation on them
So I want

1. Change value of X to 10
2. Change the array values to Integer

How can I do that in Java?

Comment: it does not change the value of x too i try now

Comment: okay work what about change array to integer

Comment: iam sorry i really dont know this point i start java from 2 day only and i dont know this point

Comment: This is pretty nit picky Amr but rather you learn early then later. In Java we define arrays like this `String[] arrayName` instead of how you have done it, `String arrayName[]`. They do the same thing, but the java convention is to do it the first way. I almost missed your array at the beginning. Depending on your coding experience, it might be a hard habit to break but someone here will mention it to you sooner or later.

Comment: thank you for your advice you welcome :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can turn a `String[]` into a `int[]`.

```
String[] arr = {"1","2"};
int[] intArray = new int[arr.length];
for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
}
```

You essentially loop through the `String[]` and parse each `String` using `Integer.parseInt`.

Or if you are working in Java 8:

```
String[] arr = {"1","2"};
int[] intArray = Arrays.stream(arr).mapToInt(i -> Integer.parseInt(i)).toArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

In java it is not possible to compare strings using " == "

Try:

```
if (firstString.equals(secondString){
//code...
}
```

I know thats confusing, as in many other programming languages a double = can compare strings, but again in Java that is not possible.

Edit: to compare Strings ignoring lower and upper case, use

```
string1.equalsIgnoreCase(string2)
```

Thats also possible:

```
if(string.equals("X"))
```

So in your case, use

```
if(arr[i].equals("10")
```

Comment: Thank You Please last thing i want to Change array to Integer all value in it please iam biggner and i dont know this point i java as i work in python and c++ this new

Comment: okay it works i want to change arrays value to integer and thank you

Comment: To make an int out of a string use Integer.parseInt(string_or_array_value)

Comment: Also please be so kind to mark the question as answered, so other people with the same problem can find it.

Comment: Okay i will make that thank you

Comment: but it give me error when i use Integer.parseInt(arr)? why

Comment: Wait, how do you want to make an integer out of a whole array? If you want the length if the array use arr.length   so what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: okay okay thank you i make it :D